# How to increase the "pull to refresh" distance (threshold) in React Native

Tags: android, ios, react-native

My screen is like this:

```
<ScrollView>
 <WebView
  scrollEnabled={false}
 />
</ScrollView>
```

The "pull to refresh" distance of ScrollView is too short and makes scroll behavior too sensitive, so I want to increase this distance (both Android and IOS). I try using event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y but when scrolling to the top, it does not work (the minimum value is 0).
By the way, my WebView has horizontally scrollable, I want to lock the scroll direction on Android (like the "directionalLockEnabled" prop on IOS).
Can I do without 3rd party package?